# How can fixed multi join in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have problem with my code. I finished the code, but when I uploaded it to hosting, I have a problem when I need get details by many tables using `join`.

For example in model:

```
function get_details($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('personal_info');
    $this->db->where('p_id', $id);
    $this->db->join('supply', 'supply.s_p_id = personal_info.p_id');
    $this->db->join('family_info', 'family_info.f_p_id = personal_info.p_id');
    $this->db->join('social_info', 'social_info.s_p_id = personal_info.p_id');
    $this->db->join('vote', 'vote.v_num = personal_info.std_type');
    /* have many more table join */
    $this->db->query('SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1'); 
    return $this->db->get();        

}
```

When calling it in controller and display values in view just loading and don't see any result just "blank page " but when using it in localhost, I get the values normally.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can echo the `$this->db->last_query()` in your local to get the executed query and test it.

You also need to specify the join type as CodeIgniter [documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html). e.g `$this->db->join('supply', 'supply.s_p_id = personal_info.p_id', 'LEFT');`

> if you need a specific type of JOIN you can specify it via the third
>   parameter of the function. Options are: left, right, outer, inner,
>   left outer, and right outer.

I Believe this will solve the issue.